# BigQuery supposedly hourly partitioned tables show up as different tables

Tags: google-bigquery, database-partitioning

When I push data to BQ using pandas (`to_gbq()`) the ones which are supposed to be hourly partitioned tables, show up as different tables with same naming convention e.g.:

[image]

The naming convention I made for each table is `yyyyMMddHH` as can be seen in above screenshot. Same as described in official documentation here:

> A valid entry from the bound DATE, TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column.
> Currently, date values prior to 1960-01-01 and later than 2159-12-31
> are placed in a shared UNPARTITIONED partition. NULL values reside in
> an explicit NULL partition.
>
> Partitioning identifiers must follow the following formats:
>
> yyyyMMddHH for hourly partitioning.
>
> yyyyMMdd for daily partitioning.
>
> yyyyMM for monthly partitioning.
>
> yyyy for yearly partitioning.

However still they does show up as separate tables. I also made simple daily partitioned tables with daily naming conventions and they seem to show up fine. Problem is just with the hourly partitioned tables.

Comment: Can you share the code? It seems that you are creating different tables for each hour. My guess is that the same thing is happening for the daily table but BigQuery UI "group" them into their prefix and you get a drop down menu. This is an UI optimisation, they are in fact multiple table. Partitioned table do not need naming convention https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables. What you are ding is sharding into multiple daily/hourly table

Comment: The text you are quoting do not refer to table names or naming convention but to the configuration of the partition specification. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#sql

Comment: Ohh yesss primarily thats true! I will add code and more info but yeah that "grouping" works well for daily tables but not for hourly ones. Even code that I am gonna post, I do not think is culprit as on BQ they showed up in exactly same format which UI groups.

Comment: I think your question is misleading. You are talking about partitioned table. But infact you are not using partitioned tables, you are creating regular table with different names. You should use a single partitioned table configuring it the partitioning strategy depending on your needs. The default Is daily. You can do hourly, however there is a limit of 4000 partition per table. So one table can hold only about 166 days of data. I suggest you are thinking to your strategy depending on the optimization you need.

Comment: The UI grouping is not related to partitioning. It is just a "beautification".

Comment: @Hamza Hi, have you solved it?

Comment: No the issue is still unresolved